# Transformer Problem

Tags: power, transformer, power-electronics

I can't understand the solution of this problem. While computing secondary phase current, referred to the primary side. Is not it necessary to multiply by PF on denominator? Is the solution wrong or am I wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here in the expression

i = kVA(Rated) / V(Rated).

As it is KVA(Magnitude of vector sum of both real and imaginary powers), the i value got is the sum of both the real and imaginary currents.

So here there is no need to divide or multiply the expression by a power factor term.

Had the power been kW(Real power), then the expression has to be divided by the power factor as told by you.